# Chance of overlap of random sets of an interval.

Tags: probability-theory

One of my friends asked me something equivalent to this, and none of us knew how to solve it.

For fixed $0<w<1$, there are two random sets $A\subset[0,1]$ and $B\subset[0,1]$ such that

$$\int_{A}1\,\mathrm dx=\int_{B}1\,\mathrm dx=w$$

What is the probability that $A$ is disjoint from $B$ and what is the probability that $A=B$.

Neither of us know much about probability and we don't know any methods of solving a problem like this.

Comment: In the title you say "subinterval", in the post you say "set". Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is if the OP meant 'set'.
The $x$ values are all independent.
For any value $x$, the probability that $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$ is $w^2$.  The probability that they don't clash at $x$ is $1-w^2$.  So the probability that $A$ and $B$ clash nowhere would be $(1-w^2)^\infty=0$.
Likewise, the probability they are equal is $(w^2+(1-w)^2)^\infty=0$
On the other hand, consider intervals $A$ and $B$.  Their left-hand ends are $x$ and $y$, both between 0 and $1-w$.  Now consider the square $[0,1-w]^2$.  $A$ and $B$ overlap if $|x-y|\leq w$.  The area of that region, divided by the area of the square, is your probability.
The area of $|x-y|\leq w$ is $(1-w)^2-area(x-y>w)-area(y-x>w)=(1-w)^2-(1-2w)^2$ if $w<1/2$  So the probability they overlap is $1-(1-2w)^2/(1-w)^2$.
Again, the probability they are the same is 0. This time it is because $P(x=y)=\int_x^x dx=0$.